# Why is Fetch body going always null

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fetch

I have this class:

```
public class StatisticFormDTO
{
    public StatisticFormDTO()
    {
        FilterIds = new List<int>();
    }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public IList<int> FilterIds { get; set; }
}


    [HttpPost]
    
     public async Task<IActionResult> GetStatsBySalesman([FromBody] StatisticFormDTO parameters)
     {}
```

and in the view

```
 let data = new Object();
    data.startDate = startDate;
    data.endDate = endDate;
    data.filterIds = provenanceIds;

    let json = JSON.stringify(data);

    let url = "/Dossiers/GetStatsBySalesman";

    await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: json
    })
```

I'm using asp .net 5.0 mvc, the parameter allways come null.
I've did it this way many times and always works fine.
I'd appretiate some help

Comment: I don't see any reason why the body would be empty. Use the Network tab of DevTools to see what you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

Using `new Object();` causes this error, instead use `new StatisticFormDTO();`